# Is there a query to know if a particular privilege has been granted for a mysql user?

Tags: mysql

I know `SHOW GRANTS` can be used to find all privileges for a particular user but what if I just wanted to know if the current user has lets say `RELOAD` privileges? is there a query for that, that will simply return true/false? or is parsing the string result from `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT USER` the only way?

Comment: ```SELECT Reload_priv FROM mysql.user WHERE user = @username /* AND host IN (@hostname, '%') */ ;```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```sql
SELECT Reload_priv 
FROM mysql.user 
WHERE user = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1) COLLATE utf8_general_ci
  AND host = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1) COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Will work only when the user in `mysql.user` is specified with definite host (i.e. any pattern/mask is not used). I.e. if user `foo` is authenticated as `foo@localhost` using `foo@%` value in `mysql.user` then none row will be found.

Adjust collation if needed.